Log JWT failures for secuirty monitoring
Does Spring Security Resource Server with JWT (Servlet stack) allow logging warnings / errors when invalid tokens are received. For example to aid with OWASP API10 (2019) "Insufficient Logging and Monitoring": How to allow monitor for an increased number of rejected tokens, e.g. due to invalid signature?
I tried researching using documentation and some internet searches, but so far did not find information related to this. (Spring Security describes how to set DEBUG/TRACE setting, but I think that is not reasonable for an production environment.)

and just now I discover events in the documentation, maybe looks like I might be able to answer my own question... https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/authentication/events.html

Here are the latest docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/events.html
